# R replace multiple column value from another dataframe

Tags: r, replace

first dataframe like this, with quite few columns:

| name | C1 | C2 | C3 | .... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2 | 3 | 5 | ..... |
| b | 4 | 5 | 6 | .... |
| c | 6 | 2 | 3 | .... |

second dataframe like this:

| id | C_name |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | apple |
| 3 | banana |
| 4 | orange |
| 5 | grape |
| 6 | kiwi |

I would like to replace the numbers in the first dataframe with the names in second dataframe, it should look like this

| name | C1 | C2 | C3 | .... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | apple | banana | grape | ..... |
| b | orange | grape | kiwi | .... |
| c | kiwi | apple | banana | .... |

thank you

Comment: What did you try to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
dat2vec <- setNames(dat2$C_name, dat2$id)
dat1[2:4] <- lapply(dat1[2:4], function(z) dat2vec[as.character(z)])
dat1
#   name     C1     C2     C3  ....
# 1    a  apple banana  grape .....
# 2    b orange  grape   kiwi  ....
# 3    c   kiwi  apple banana  ....
```

or

```r
dat1[2:4] <- lapply(dat1[2:4], function(z) {
  ind <- match(z, dat2$id)
  replace(z, !is.na(ind), dat2$C_name[ind])
})
```

---

Data

```r
dat1 <- structure(list(name = c("a", "b", "c"), C1 = c("apple", "orange", "kiwi"), C2 = c("banana", "grape", "apple"), C3 = c("grape", "kiwi", "banana"), .... = c(".....", "....", "....")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
dat2 <- structure(list(id = 2:6, C_name = c("apple", "banana", "orange", "grape", "kiwi")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```